# How can we mount multiple Google Drive accounts on our system using google-drive-ocamlfuse?

Tags: command-line, google-drive

I am trying to mount multiple Google Drive accounts on my system using google-drive-ocamlfuse but I am unable to access multiple accounts.

Can anyone tell what the problem is?

Comment: You'll have to tell us what is happening first. Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to mount multiple google drives you will need to use the following procedure:

1. Create a new directory for the new Google Drive, for example `mkdir /mnt/google-drive1`
2. Then issue the below command:

   ```
   google-drive-ocamlfuse -label label /mnt/google-drive1
   ```
3. A new browser tab will open asking you to allow the software access to your google drive.

If you already signed in with another gmail account you will need to sign out and sign in with the ID of the new Google drive you want to mount.

Comment: terminal says there is no such command as 'google-drive-ocamlfuse'. What now?