# How can we use multiple Googledrive in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

I wanted to use multiple google drive in Ubuntu ,like we use in our cellphones , we can switch drive according to our requirement . So is there any steps to get that or I have to download any package for that..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368874/can-google-drive-desktop-be-used-on-ubuntu  https://askubuntu.com/questions/887755/how-can-we-mount-multiple-google-drive-accounts-on-our-system-using-google-drive

Comment: @Johan Palych thanks , it worked for me,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we mount multiple Google Drive accounts on our system using google-drive-ocamlfuse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887755/how-can-we-mount-multiple-google-drive-accounts-on-our-system-using-google-drive)